# Need help with set equality proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So the question is to prove 
$(A \cap B) \setminus (B \cup C) = A \cap (B \setminus C)$

I started from the left side, establishing that $x$ is an element of both $A$ and $B$, and that $x$ is not an element of $C$ but then I get stuck. How do I make it look like the right side?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

$A\backslash B = A \cap \bar{B}$

Plug this into your formula on both sides and simplify to get a much easier problem.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to see it:
$$A\cap B\subset B\subset B\cup C.$$